# Jquery Validate and send form with a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#alta").validate();
});
</script>
<form id="alta" method="post" action="<?= $this->Html->url('/'); ?>alta">
    <label>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="field required" name="data[name]">
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="alta.submit(); return false;" id="button" class="button">Send</a>
```

And my problem is I do not use submit input, need to use a link, but submits the form and not valid.

thanks

Comment: onClick="alta.submit() will have same effect of <input type=submit>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a submit button you need to check the form is valid manually.

Firstly, remove the `onclick` attribute from your HTML - this is not a good method of attaching events.

```
<a href="#" id="button" class="button">Send</a>
```

Then place this in your jQuery code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    if ($("#alta").valid()) {
        $("#alta").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

inside the click handler validate the form.

```
   $("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#alta").valid()){
        //submit
        $("#alta").submit();
    } 
    else
       return false;
  });
```

also (after reading the comments) you dont need to validate the form in document ready